# "non-assigned" or "un-assigned" inventory?

Tags: word-choice, prefixes

I am writing up a procedure regarding inventory that is not assigned to any specific employee of the company and would like to know if I should refer to this inventory as "non-assigned" inventory, or "un-assigned" inventory.

Answer (score 1):

[Non-assigned](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22non-assigned%22) has 77k Google hits

[Nonassigned](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22nonassigned%22) has just under 8k

[Un-assigned](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22un-assigned%22) has a bit over 36k hits

and [unassigned](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22unassigned%22) has 5.9 million and a dictionary definition

> not allocated or set aside for a specific purpose

and, as a bonus, [not assigned](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22not%20assigned%22) has 5.9 million hits as well

... so I think you can conclude an answer from that as to the most common usage. *Unassigned* would be fine.